# WPF Multithreading and binding - no updates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to change property of ProgressBar - IsInterminate to true during new task. I've added DataContext to my statusbar (parent of progressbar) and binding to progress bar property:

```
<StatusBar>
        <StatusBar.DataContext>
            <viemodel:EventsViewModel/>
        </StatusBar.DataContext>
<ProgressBar Name="pbProgress" IsIndeterminate="{Binding Pennding}"/>
</StatusBar>
```

in ViewModel (implements INotifyPropertychanged) I've added property:

```
 private static bool _pending = false;

    public bool Pennding
    {
        get { return _pending; }
        set
        {
            _pending = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and trying to change that property in command:

```
App.Current.Invoke(() => new EventsViewModel { Pennding = true }));
```

but nothing is changing! I've checked Debug infomations about binding and there was no errors.

Comment: The instance you create in your lambda isn't actually bound to anything. Your StatusBar creates its own instance and listens to its change notifications. But since you don't change that instance, nothing happens there. Can you post the code of your other ViewModel where you start the task?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/icipx8tn here is my command where I do my work. I've addes static EventsViewModel field to this class and x:Name to DataContect to Status bar and it works - but I don't know why.

Comment: Did you set DataContext at the beggining?

Comment: Tesy' I've added context to status bar and check it during debbuging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the specific instance of `EventsViewModel` that you have bound - you are currently just creating a new instance using the `new` syntax.

Your code should rather be:

```
<StatusBar.DataContext>
    <viemodel:EventsViewModel x:Name="MyEventVM"/>
</StatusBar.DataContext>
<ProgressBar Name="pbProgress" IsIndeterminate="{Binding Pennding}"/>
```

and followed by...

```
App.Current.Invoke(() => { MyEventVM.Pennding = true; }));
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But if I set back property to static I don't get same value using Pennding property for every instance?

Comment: The notification will be raised for the current instance, which is the new one. There is no way to raise the notification for the instance which is bound by changing the static backing field. Also I really wouldn't do that - it's extremely confusing having an instance member with a static backing field. It breaks SOLID.

Comment: I don't get it.
So I should add "MyEventVM" to my ViewModel class with the same name as in my command class?

Comment: The ultimate point is you would need to have a way to access the specific instance that you have bound to the control otherwise the change in the property cannot notify the UI properly.

Comment: Since OP mentioned MVVM I'd assume there's another ViewModel behind the UserControl containing the StatusBar. So the DataContext should be set through a binding: <StatusBar DataContext="{Binding MyEventVM}">. Of course that's just an assumption as long as we don't see more code.

Comment: This progress bar is in status bar which data context is EventsViewModel